# Android ClassNotFoundException and dependent projects

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

We have got working android application which was published in Google Play in 04.2012. We didnt touch it for months.

In December we decided to make a Christmas update. However, the programmer who wrote this project left us in September, so we had to download his code from repository. It turned out, that repository version was lack of 2 projects which our app was depent on, so we had to download them from web (they are open source ones) and add as denendent projects (project properties -> android -> "library" section -> Add).

We made several small changes, everything worked fine and there were no questions about it.

But! At some point something went wrong:

when debug-version of the project (signed with debug key) is installed onto device (real device, not emulator), it works;

when release-version of the project (signed with release key) is installed onto device, it crashes at start. Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{packageName/packageName.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "packageName.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/packageName-1.apk

How we fixed this: we changed the way those 2 open-source projects (mentioned above) are added to our app. In particular, we removed project dependency and added jar-files dependency instead. So it began working.
I cannot understand what was wrong in using those ones as library projects. Why it began working only after we added jar-files? Probably someone can help to understand it.

Comment: What is the question here? You had a ClassNotFoundException and you dealt with it by replacing the way your libs are 'linked'. The reason is that you did not sign the two dependencies with the release key and they did not end up in the same place :)

Comment: It is probably that when those projects are added as project dependencies, they are not included in your APK in release build.

Comment: Sounds like something related to proguard. I think so because it occured when you exported the app. That is when proguard kicks in and  obfuscates your code. As a result some classes may have been renamed and thus generating the issue you mentioned.

Comment: Except no ProGuard was mentioned.

Comment: To Shark: how can I actually sign dependent projects if they are added to my apk at compilation time? To neevek: the strange thing is that not found class belongs to app's package, not to dependent projects' packages. To Paul: we dont use ProGuard.

Comment: Struggling with a similar problem here. My guess is that your main activity inherits directly from one of the missing classes. The class loader complains about your activity class even though it's one of the inherited classes that are missing. (In my case, I'm thinking that I didn't properly export Android-support-v4.jar. I'll find out tomorrow, I guess whether that was it).